# Differentiability of $\operatorname{dist}(x,\partial \Omega)$ function

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $\Omega$  be a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with smooth boundary and set

$$\phi(x)=\operatorname{dist} (x,\partial \Omega) =\inf_{y\in \partial \Omega} |x-y|$$

for $x\in \overline{\Omega}$.

Is there a subset of $\Omega$ where $\phi$ is differentiable?

I'm thinking a subset like $N_s=\{x \in \Omega \mid \operatorname{dist}(x,\partial \Omega) < s\}$.

(for example, in the unitary ball, $\phi$ is not differentiable in the center but it is in $N_s$ for $s<1$)